# How fix a smoothie drain pipe in kitchen double sink

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, drainage, kitchen-sink

To solve the problem is de 2 draining pipe are draining too slowly 
;DOUBLE SINK WITH DRAIN HOLE 40mm
;can I joint the two sink drain together with T-fitting at the center of the 2 sink and then out with 2’inch water trap then only totally drain out[image][image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

Comment: it is not clear what the problem is

Comment: Hey thanks for feedback.. I Hv just share another picture.. is A better than B

Comment: Is the rest of the piping from the sink 2” now or are you increasing the size? Fewer restrictions and larger pipes will always decrease resistance and therefore increase flow (whether or not its enough of an increase in flow though...), however there is not enough information about your current configuration and desired flow rate out of the sink to know which solution to recommend. Also, before changing out pipes, have you already had the drains snaked to remove clogs?